# Preorder Traversal (Binary Tree) - Iterative Method

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree

I am implementing Preorder Traversal of Binary Tree (without recursion). The following code runs into an infinite loop. I cannot understand what's happening

```
void Tree::n_preorder()
{
    Node* temp;        
    stack s;
    cout<<"\nPreorder: ";
    while(1)
    {
        s.push(root);
        while(1)
        {
            temp = s.pop();
            cout<<temp->data;
            if(temp->right)
            {
                s.push(temp->right);        //Push right child
            }
            if(s.isEmpty())
            {
                break;
            }
            if(temp->left)
            {
                s.push(temp->left);         //Push left child
            }
        }
    }
}
```

isEmpty() function of Stack

```
int isEmpty()
{
  return top==-1;
}
```

Comment: Remove the 1st while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer loop is never exited: its `while` condition is always true, and it has no `break`. The only `break` you have will break out of the inner loop, but not the outer one.

You should not need nested loops to do this. And when you have just one loop, it makes no sense to break out of it without putting the left child on the stack, so remove that conditional break, and instead make `!s.isEmpty()` the condition of your loop:

```
void Tree::n_preorder()
{
    Node* node;        
    stack nodeStack;
    cout << "\nPreorder:";
    nodeStack.push(root);
    while (!nodeStack.isEmpty())
    {
        node = nodeStack.pop();
        cout << " " << node->data;
        // As a stack is LIFO (last-in-first-out), we add the node's children 
        // on the stack in reversed order, so they get output in the correct order.
        if (node->right)
        {
            nodeStack.push(node->right);
        }
        if (node->left)
        {
            nodeStack.push(node->left);
        }
    }
}
```

Some other remarks:

- I do not find it useful to have comments like *"push left child"*... as that is just repeating -- almost verbatim -- what one can already see in the corresponding line of code. Comments should be made about a higher level of abstraction, and give some explanation as to "why?". I added such a comment in the above code to illustrate this point.
- Use more descriptive variable names. `temp` and `s` are not giving away much.
- You'll want to output a space to separate the different data outputs.